# starting 1 timer clock after another and looping it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, timer

I have two count-down timers in my website. One timer would start automatically, but the next one should only start only after the 1st is completed. This should loop on forever, i.e. starting one clock after another.

Here is the code which I tried:

```
function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
    if (newtime !== '00:00:00') {
        setTimeout(count, 1000);
    } else {
        count1();
    }

}

count();

function count1() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById('hms1').innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours();
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById('hms1').innerHTML = newtime;
    if (newtime !== '00:00:00') {
        setTimeout(count, 1000);
    } else {
        count();
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hms">00:00:10</div>


<div id="hms1">00:02:10</div>
```

I am unable to make this work. Help!!

Comment: document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML, how it works. Add html code also

Comment: a different approach to this whole thing: https://jsfiddle.net/3qrrduqw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is nearly there - with a couple of small issues:

1. `time.setHours` is missing a parameter on line 23, should be as follows:

   `var time = new Date(); time.setHours(pieces[0]);`
2. Line 30 should call the alternate function:

   `setTimeout(count1, 1000);`
3. Only one counter should be running at a time, so no need to for the last line (`count1()`).

Here's an [updated JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lowuboyoba/edit?html,js,output).

However, a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) solution here would be much more appropriate to avoid having to manage two functions:

```
var currentTimer = 'hms';
var alternateTimer = 'hms1';

function count() {
  var timer = document.getElementById(currentTimer);
  
  var startTime = timer.innerHTML;
  var pieces = startTime.split(':');
  var time = new Date();
  
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
  
  // Update DOM
  timer.innerHTML = newtime;

  if(newtime === '00:00:00') {
    // Swap the two timers
    currentTimer = [alternateTimer, alternateTimer = currentTimer][0];
  }
  
  setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

count();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do you make the initial timing constant. Cause the current code starts from 00:00:00,rather than the initial time.

Comment: You could always store the initial time in the code:and revert the timer to it when swapping the two timers. Add as Line 1: `var initialTime = '00:00:10';` Add when swapping the timers: `document.getElementById(alternateTimer).innerHTML = initialTime`

Answer (score 0):

`count` should start a timeout to run `count1`, and the converse:

```
initial_count = 5; // say 5 sec. count-down
initial_count1 = 7;
ic = initial_count;
function count() {
  ic--
  if (ic>=0)
    setTimeout(count, 1000); // refresh every 1sec.
  else {
    ic = initial_count1;
    count1();
  }
}

function count1() {
  ic--
  if (ic>=0)
    setTimeout(count1, 1000); // refresh every 1sec.
  else {
    ic = initial_count;
    count();
  }
}

count(); // start the first alarm.
```

Add all the remaining of your logic...

Comment: this does not start count1 after count has been terminated.

Comment: I understand you want two count-down that update at some refresh rate. Need some edit.

Comment: just to make things more clear. Once clock 1 reaches 00:00:00, clock 2 (count1) should start. That is why I used the if statement, but I am unable to work it out. Hope this makes my situation clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date(); time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML=newtime;
   if(newtime!=='00:00:00'){
    setTimeout(count, 1000);
   }else
   {
     count1();
   }

}

count();


function count1() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById('hms1').innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date(); time.setHours();
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById('hms1').innerHTML=newtime;
    if(newtime!=='00:00:00' && newtime!=='00:00:01' ){
        setTimeout(count, 1000);
    }else
    {
        count();
    }

   }

 count1();
```